# Convergence/divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n!)^2/[(n^2)!]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I am looking for an explanation that is easily explainable to a Calc. II student and makes use of the usual convergence tests.

> Determine the convergence/divergence of 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(n!)^2}{(n^2)!}$$

By the ratio test, we have
$$\begin{align}\dfrac{[(n+1)!]^2}{[(n+1)^2]!} \cdot \dfrac{(n^2)!}{(n!)^2}&=\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{(n+1)^2[(n+1)^2-1][(n+1)^2-2]\cdots(n^2+1)} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{[(n+1)^2-1][(n+1)^2-2]\cdots(n^2+1)}
\end{align}$$
and taking the limit as $n \to \infty$, we obtain $0$. Hence, the series is absolutely convergent, and thus convergent.

Is this correct? If so, is there perhaps an easier way to approach this problem?

Comment: Holy holy, $(n^2)!$ is *so much* larger than $n!^2$ than the main term of the series converges to zero almost instantly. In particular such series is trivially convergent.

Comment: You established the convergence of the series in 2 lines, is that not a sufficiently easy method?

Comment: since binomail coefficient $2n$ choose $n$ is a positive integer, we see $(2n)! > (n!)^2.$ Then $(n^2)!$ is much bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the series is with positive terms we can apply ratio test and since the limit of the ratio is $0$ yes it is convergent (we don’t need to refer to absolute convergence).

As an alternative we could use Stirling but I think that ratio test is really a nice way in this case.